# How to declare all list items are function variables?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

There is a list `xy = List[x, y]` and an expression `f = x^2 + y^2`. I would like to get a function `ff[x_,y_]` in such a way that its variables are the elements of the list and assign this function to the expression `f`, `ff[x_, y_] = f`, `ff[1, 1] = 2`

How to write the part inside brackets `ff[...]` through the list (not to write each variable separately)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the comments by the OP, which are different from the question as written,

### Solution

The [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) with [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)s (`_`) can be achieved by [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)ing `Pattern[#,Blank[]]&`like this

```
Pattern[#,Blank[]]& /@ {a,b,c,d,e}
(* {a_,b_,c_,d_,e_} *)
```

Or using [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) intead of `Map`.

```
Thread[Pattern[{a, b, c}, _]]
```

### Example

Now for the function definition

```
ff[Apply[Sequence, Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ {a, b, c}]] :=  a^2 + b^2 + c^2
```

or

```
ff[Sequence @@ Thread[Pattern[{a, b, c}, _]]] := a^2 + b^2 + c^2
```

Both give

```
ff[x, y, z]
(* x^2 + y^2 + z^2 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you

```
xyz = List[x_, y_, z_]
ff[Sequence @@ xyz] := x + y + z^2
```

And now

```
ff[1, 2, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ff[x, y, z]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But what is the purpose of doing this? Why not just write this in first place?

```
ff[x_,y_,z_] := x + y + z^2
```

Comment: Thanks! How to make such a design ```List[x_, y_, z_]``` from such ```List[x, y, z]``` using a loop, In other words, how to add this character ```_```?

Comment: `(# _) & /@ {x, y, z}`

Comment: @Daniel Huber, thanks! Yes, it's what I meant

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f, ff]
xy = List[x, y]; f = x^2 + y^2;
```

You can apply [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) to `{xy, f}` to define `ff`:

```
ff = Function @@ {xy, f};

ff[w, z]
```

> ```
> w^2 + z^2
> ```

```
ff[5, 3]
```

> ```
> 34
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the interpretation as written in the original question, I gather that the important part is to *"not to write each variable separately"*. Compared with [Nasser's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285331/10397) this works for any number of parameters.

### Solution

Here I use [`BlankSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html) (`__`) which  *"is a pattern object that can stand for any sequence of one or more Wolfram Language expressions"*, and [`Dot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) (`.`) that *"gives products of vectors, matrices, and tensors"*.

```
 ff[x__] := {x} . {x}
```

### Examples

```
ff[a, b, c]
(* a^2 + b^2 + c^2 *)

ff[x, y]
(* x^2 + y^2 *)

ff @@ Range[9]
(* 285 *)

ff @@ Array[c, 9]
(* c[1]^2 + c[2]^2 + c[3]^2 + c[4]^2 + c[5]^2 + c[6]^2 + c[7]^2 + c[8]^2 + c[9]^2 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I meant a little different, let's imagine that the function  can be absolutely anything combination of x and y.

Comment: I mean, If the expression with variables is large, then it is too expensive to rewrite it in this form (in that form {x} . {x}).

Comment: @MamMam My answer addresses what you asked in your question. If what you need is different, then probably you could edit your question and explain in more detail, with more examples.

Comment: @MamMam, Do you mean something like `Pattern[#,Blank[]]& /@ {a,b,c,d,e}`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the not very clear description of the problem. Yes your last message is what I meant